# "Too many fields to unpack" error, even though I got equal amount of fields on the left as on the right side

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

Pretty simple code, I have a tuple extraAccessions with two values, a string and a list. I want to loop through the extraAccessions (which is only one in this example) and use the first and second values in the tuple.

```
extraAccessions=('MS:1000505',['value','unitName'])
for accession, fieldIdentifiers in extraAccessions:
    [do something]
```

However, this gives

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

When I do

```
print (extraAccessions)
```

I get

```
('MS:1000505', ['value', 'unitName'])
```

Which seems two values to me, exactly what is asked in

```
for accession, fieldIdentifiers in extraAccessions:
```

So I don't see why I get this error.

---

edit:

And when I do

```
for accession in extraAccessions:
     print accession
```

I get the first element MS:1000505

Comment: To achieve what you want just do:   accession, fieldIdentifiers = extraAccessions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's examine your code:

```
extraAccessions=('MS:1000505',['value','unitName'])
for accession, fieldIdentifiers in extraAccessions:
    ...
```

Here, you are iterating over the tuple (`extraAccessions`) that has two entries:

1. `'MS:1000505'`
2. `['value','unitName']`

You're then trying to unpack *each entry in turn* into the two variables. This doesn't work for the first entry since it is not of length two.

If you're looking to unpack the two entries into the two variables, simply use:

```
accession, fieldIdentifiers = extraAccessions
```

That will set

1. `accession` to `'MS:1000505'`
2. `fieldIdentifiers` to `['value','unitName']`

Comment: A fix to make this code work close to as written might be to write `extraAccessions` as `(('MS:1000505',  ['value','unitName']),)`.

Comment: Correct, I'll accept this answer when I can.

@Wilduck: thanks! The for-loop is in a library that I'm using which I don't want to change the code of, but using your suggestion helps

Answer (score 0):

Here Python treats tuple as a sequence, so it tries to match (in turn) each item in the sequence to your pattern and fails